# Automatically showing div on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a simple problem I'm having, but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out. If any of you could help me with this, I would be much obliged.

I'm using JQuery to make a menu appear when a user hovers over a certain div. The menu will be displayed on the top left of the div.
I got this to work, but when I try to click on a menu item of the div that appeared, the div disappears again, because the mouse is technically not over the div, but over the menu.

In the example below, "#blockMenu" is the menu that dynamically appears. I fade the current div ($this)) out a bit, to emphasize the menu as well.

I use the following code to make this happen:

```
$("div.editable").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.25);
    $('#Menu').css("position", "absolute");
    $("#Menu").css("top", $(this).offset().top);
    $("#Menu").css("left", $(this).offset().left);
    $("#Menu").css("zIndex", "10000");
    $('#Menu').show();
 }, function (e) { // on mouseout
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
    $("#Menu").hide();
 });
```

I want the menu to disappear when the cursor leaves the div, while the div remains faded out when the cursor is on the menu. When the cursor leaves the menu AND the div at the same time, the div should fade back in and the menu should disappear.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could edit my code to make this work correctly?

Thank you very much for any help you can give me.

Comment: Can I get a look at the html please

Comment: Oh, for Goodnes' sake, use an object literal to set the styles...

Comment: Make the menu a child of the div and it will work.

Comment: @Šime Vidas : could you clarify what you mean? Do you mean that I should store my $("#Menu") in a separate variable and use that variable to set all those styles? 

I was planning on doing that in the end, when I clean up my code. If you meant something else, please clarify.

Comment: @Steven Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/c58mt/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `:hover` pseudo class, that's likely to help the situation. You'll lose animation effects, but it could sure make things easier, and take javascript out of the picture

Answer (score 0):

Add a hover function for the menu and set some state when the mouse is hovering over the menu and only take the menu down if the mouse is not over the div AND not over the menu.

Comment: I have tried that, but it seems that the .hover() on the main div is called before the .hover() on the menu is called. Therefore, the main div still fades out.
Any ideas?